# RestEasy client freezes with custom httpEngine

Tags: java, resteasy, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a RestEasy client that I want to set `NoConnectionReuseStrategy` to. For this purpose, I create a custom instance of ApacheHttpClient43Engine with the desired settings.

However, when I make several requests one after the other, the application freezes (the request is sent to the server, but no response is received).

```java
    private static final ResteasyClient RESTEASY_CLIENT;

    static {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                                                .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
                                                .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new NoConnectionReuseStrategy())
                                                .build();

        ApacheHttpClientEngine engine = new ApacheHttpClient43Engine(httpClient);

        RESTEASY_CLIENT = ((ResteasyClientBuilder) ClientBuilder.newBuilder())
                .httpEngine(engine)
                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

//        RESTEASY_CLIENT = (ResteasyClient) ClientBuilder.newClient();
        System.out.println(RESTEASY_CLIENT.httpEngine());

        RESTEASY_CLIENT.register(new BasicAuthentication(SERVER_USERNAME, SERVER_PASSWORD));
        RESTEASY_CLIENT.register(new AuthorizationFilter());
        RESTEASY_CLIENT.register(new LoggerFilter());
    }
```

Setting a timeout does not throw an exception or change behavior
In case I use

```java
    private static final ResteasyClient RESTEASY_CLIENT;

    static {
        CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
                                                .setConnectionManager(new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager())
                                                .setConnectionReuseStrategy(new NoConnectionReuseStrategy())
                                                .build();

        ApacheHttpClientEngine engine = new ApacheHttpClient43Engine(httpClient);

//        RESTEASY_CLIENT = ((ResteasyClientBuilder) ClientBuilder.newBuilder())
//                .httpEngine(engine)
//                .connectTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//                .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
//                .build();

        RESTEASY_CLIENT = (ResteasyClient) ClientBuilder.newClient();
        System.out.println(RESTEASY_CLIENT.httpEngine());

        RESTEASY_CLIENT.register(new BasicAuthentication(SERVER_USERNAME, SERVER_PASSWORD));
        RESTEASY_CLIENT.register(new AuthorizationFilter());
        RESTEASY_CLIENT.register(new LoggerFilter());
    }
```

The problem disappears
In both cases, the trace message from println outputs

> org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient43

Comment: I'm guessing, but maybe the number of file descriptors runs out because you're not using sockets.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins it's only about 20-30 requests before blocking. At the OS level, everything works correctly. There are no error messages or the entire application crashing. In this case, I just don't know what to give as additional information.